# Position a text over image containing div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know there are several similar questions, but I couldn't find solution for my situation

```css
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
img{
  max-height: 100px;
}
.image-holder-div{
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-holder-div">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
  </div>
  <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
  <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
 </div>
```

This is the situation.
I need the image to be in right place where it is now. (with certain positioning)
And I need to put text over the image holder div. But the main question is to do that without using `position:absolute` for text.
I uzed `z-index` but no result.

Comment: what about using image as background..?

Comment: I used and that is a trick to overcome this issue, but I am looking for better solution

Comment: use position:relative on p tags

Comment: you can use css property float:right

Comment: @SahilDhir Perfect, thanks, it solved my issue!

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Kindly accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your **p tags** `position:relative` and this will solve your problem :)

> Below is working snippet:

```css
.parent-div {
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

img {
  max-height: 100px;
}

.image-holder-div {
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}

p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-holder-div">
    <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
  </div>
  <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
  <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `p` elements a `position: relative`. Than set `z-index: 1;` This will put the text in front of the image.

```css
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
.parent-div p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
img{
  max-height: 100px;
}
.image-holder-div{
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-holder-div">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
  </div>
  <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
  <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```css
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
img{
  max-height: 100px;
}
.image-holder-div{
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
.over {
position: relative;
z-index: 4; /* if needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-holder-div">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
  </div>
  <p class="over">some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
  <p class="over">The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that you can just use it as a background image to the `div` see below.

```css
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100px;
  background-position: right top;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <p>some text here which I need to be over the image</p>
  <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
img{
  max-height: 100px;
}
.image-holder-div{
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
.parent-div p{ 
position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="image-holder-div">
   <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
  </div>
  <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
  <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 p{
      position: relative;
    }
    .parent-div{
      margin-top: 50px;
      max-width: 350px;
      background-color: azure;
      position: relative;
      height: 400px;
    }
    img{
      max-height: 100px;
    }
    .image-holder-div{
      position: absolute;
      right: -15px;
      top: -15px;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="parent-div">
      <div class="image-holder-div">
       <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
      </div>
      <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
      <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
     </div>
```

The best solution was to give `position: relative` to p elements

Answer (score 0):

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SHABU89/jwht6y9j/)

```
.parent-div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background-color: azure;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
    z-index:-1;
}
img{
  max-height: 100px;
  z-index:-1;
}
.image-holder-div{
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.parent-div p{z-index:9999;}

<div class="parent-div">
        <div class="image-holder-div">
            <img src="http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/bof/images/b/ba/PlayStation_Logo.svg/revision/latest?cb=20130905171142">
        </div>
        <p>some text here which I need to be ober the image</p>
        <p>The same situation is here, need to be... </p>
    </div>
```